# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: params is undefined in before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  before_filter :only => :destroy do |controller| 
      controller.is_object_on_same_account_as_current_account_for_id?(controller_name.classify.constantize, params[:id])
  end
```

generates error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' 
 app/controller/controller:4
```

I thought params was always available throughout the request process... =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `controller.params[:id]` since `params` is defined for the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Try request.params[:id] or controller.request.params[:id]